# Rails loading/requiring from/within lib/schedule.rb [whenever]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, object, whenever

I've got a few questions regarding rails scheduling and class/module inclusion.

I have a class in lib/ that I want to instantiate within config/schedule.rb...do I need to require/include that class? How would I do so?

Also, I want to use a method from a module which is also in lib. Can I just access it by ModuleName.methodName(arguments) or do I need to include something to load/require it?

Currently I have something like this in schedule.rb:

```
every 32.minutes do
  instance=ClassA.new()
  runner "ModuleName.methodName(#{instance})"
end
```

I don't have any error messages, but I don't think anything is actually happening/being called.

Answer (score 1):

All whenever does is provide a nice way of generating entries in your crontab (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). So, you can use ruby in your schedule to create these entries in whatever way you like, but anything which needs to happen such as initializing a new class, or loading some config in your app or whatever, needs to happen when cron calls the task, not when you generate the crontab.

For example, if you wanted to do stuff with your models, I'd create a rake task within your app (in lib/tasks) like this:

```
namespace :whatever do
  task name_this_better: :environment do
    instance = ClassA.new()
    ModuleName.methodName(instance)
  end
end
```

Then, in your schedule, you could do:

```
every 32.minutes do
  rake "whatever:name_this_better"
end
```

This not only makes your code clearer and more organised, but it makes things more reusable.

Comment: A few questions: If I don't provide an environment, will it use the default? And also, do I leave the namespace at the start of the rake task as 'namespace' or do I fill that in with something?

Comment: @AggressiveSneeze. you should replace `:whatever` and `name_this_better` with more descriptive names. Passing in the environment means the rake task will load the rails environment you specify, making your rails code available to the rake task. You can set the environment (development, production, etc) elsewhere in your schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can using https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork as well. It's create simple ruby process (not using Cron, as `whenever` do) and have a lot options to work with.